# How to deploy/filer the respective Server base endpoint in Swagger

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, swagger, azure-pipelines, swagger-ui

I have an YAML/JSON files and we have the base serve endpoint defined as seen in the below screenshot.
How do we filter only the respective base URL for specific environment

**For instance:**
Server: dev files should be deployed to DEV environment, Stage files should be deployed to Stage environment and so on

Note: I'm using Azure pipeline for deployment.

[image]

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0):

In your current situation, in the devops pipeline, we do not have this function/option to do this. We recommend you can try to create a New [Generic service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-generic) and use it in your different deploy steps.